# Google Maps Javascript API does not open blank grey

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to develop an asp.net project using Google Maps and JavaScript. For three days my map was opening perfectly. But today the map zoom and other map control buttons are coming but map doesn't come. Instead map grey blank is coming.

[HereIsTheImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lm8A.png) and here is my js code:

```
function LoadHarita() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.3, 33.3);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: myLatlng,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
            },
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
            },
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
}
```

What's the problem? The map quota or limits? But what kind of limits for 3 days?  I didn't understand it.

Comment: that location appears to be in the middle of the sea

Comment: the function works fine apart from the location initially - try setting the zoom to a lower level, say 7 perhaps which will show the coast of Israel & Jordan with given coordinates.

Comment: nope. tried with different coordinates nothing changed.

Comment: What browsers have you tried this with? Are you developing on `localhost`?

Comment: chrome, firefox, IE. Yes I'm developing on localhost

Comment: Do not edit your post to indicate completion. If an answer solved your issue, then accept it. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys. Solved the problem. Here is the details if anyone needs it.

I opened the console by pressing F12. There was saying that i've added multiple maps.
I wrote the google map javascript codes under http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js to top of my javascript code. I deleted all these code on my js. And my map comes :) Normally i won't able to reach the map yesterday because i've added these codes yesterday. Maybe cookie is the reason. Whatever my map comes :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out it was Internet Explorer's 'Compatibility view' that was wrecking Google's Map code when running in ***localhost***. Turning compatibility view off in IE11 made it work again.

The API call limit for Google Maps is 25000/day or something. It's very unlikely you managed to hit that just by playing around while developing. Try running your code in different browsers to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Firstly thx for your comment. Tried it with chrome too but the problem isn't solved. Maybe i should make something in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc hosts

Comment: I usually work in Chrome, and didn't immediately notice it not working in IE. If you're working in Chrome, make sure your caching is turned OFF. (F12 > F1 > First option top left)

Other than that, check your console. The behaviour in your screenshot is exactly the same as what I had -- everything seems to work, but no map is actually showing up.